# How can I respond back to a non standard(non HTTP) request over Node.JS Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am sending a non-standard request i.e. not HTTP request from my browser using my own developed Firefox Add-On. I am able to receive the request on Node.JS server but I am not able to find a way to respond to the request with a static HTML page. I would like to emphasize that I not using HTTP server built over Node.JS. I just looking for a way to respond back to the client browser from which my own non-standard request was generated. I can't use http.createserver().listen(). I am using a function to fetch request generated by user. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a [`server.listen`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback), and listen to the `connect` event, read the request data, write the data you want back to the socket? I'm having trouble to see where your issue is.

Comment: It is hard to give suggestions without seeing more about this custom protocol. As answers have mentioned, you should just be able to use a standard TCP socket from `net.createServer`.

Comment: I want to know how can I respond to Non-HTTP request with HTTP response?

Answer (score 0):

Use [net.createServer](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener) instead of http.createServer.

Comment: I want to know how can I respond to Non-HTTP request with a HTTP response (Static Web-Page)?

Comment: stream = [fs.createReadStream('static_file')](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) then [stream.pipe(socket)](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options).